# How would I get a while loop to terminate when the user inputs "no"

Tags: string, while-loop, switch-statement, terminate

I have this while loop for a Blackjack Class:

```
while (playerSum < 21) {
  System.out.println("Would you like another card?");
  String input;
  System.out.flush();
  input = in.readLine();
  if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    int card3;
    Random r3 = new Random();
    card3 = r3.nextInt(11 - 2 + 1) + 2;
    switch (card3) {
      case 2: System.out.println("You were dealt a Two"); break;
      case 3: System.out.println("You were dealt a Three"); break;
      case 4: System.out.println("You were dealt a Four"); break;
      case 5: System.out.println("You were dealt a Five"); break;
      case 6: System.out.println("You were dealt a Six"); break;
      case 7: System.out.println("You were dealt a Seven"); break;
      case 8: System.out.println("You were dealt a Eight"); break;
      case 9: System.out.println("You were dealt a Nine"); break;
      case 10: System.out.println("You were dealt a Ten"); break;
      case 11: System.out.println("You were dealt a Ace"); break;
    }
    playerSum += card3;
  }
}
```

I want the loop to end when the user inputs a "no" when asked if he would like another card. Currently If i input anything but "yes" it will continue to ask `Would you like another card?'. I understand why this is happening, but I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend adding `else if input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else to the end of the if-Statement and break out of the loop.

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
    int card3;
    Random r3 = new Random();
    card3 = r3.nextInt(11 - 2 + 1) + 2;
    switch (card3) {
      case 2: System.out.println("You were dealt a Two"); break;
      case 3: System.out.println("You were dealt a Three"); break;
      case 4: System.out.println("You were dealt a Four"); break;
      case 5: System.out.println("You were dealt a Five"); break;
      case 6: System.out.println("You were dealt a Six"); break;
      case 7: System.out.println("You were dealt a Seven"); break;
      case 8: System.out.println("You were dealt a Eight"); break;
      case 9: System.out.println("You were dealt a Nine"); break;
      case 10: System.out.println("You were dealt a Ten"); break;
      case 11: System.out.println("You were dealt a Ace"); break;
    }
    playerSum += card3;
  } else {
break;
}
```

**Note:** This will break out of the loop when the user inputs anything different than "yes". If you want to break out **only** on no, use `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply fix this by adding

```
break;
```

So it would look like

```
if (no) { break;}
```

Hope this helps.